# System.AccessViolationException in Emgu.CV.dll

Tags: c#, visual-studio, emgucv

I am trying to capture a video from a file using

```
captureFrame = new Capture(FileName);
```

The program works fine with .mpg images, but when I want to capture a video from an .mp4 file I get the following error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in Emgu.CV.dll
>
> Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication 
>       that other memory is corrupt.

The weird thing is that this error occurrs only occasionally. Some time the program works just fine and then this error occurrs.

Do you have any ideas?

Thanks, B